# iOS 11 space between UIBarButtonItem

Tags: uinavigationbar, frame, uibarbuttonitem, nslayoutconstraint, ios11

I've noticed that iOS 11 has made some change to the UIBarButtonItem. After solving the sizing problem of the image of UIBarButtonItem, I find myself facing another even more strange issue.

We have a UIToolBar with several UIBarButtonItems and we used to set the width of the UIBarButtonItem as 40 and the width of the UIButton.image as 24, which leaves a nice spacing between every two UIBarButtonItems. However, in iOS 11, the space disappear.

I tried with

```
[self.deleteButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.size.mas_equalTo(CGSizeMake(40, 24));
    }];

NSLayoutConstraint *w = [self.deleteButton.imageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:24];
NSLayoutConstraint *h = [self.deleteButton.imageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:24];
w.active = YES;
h.active = YES;
```

but it doesn't work as I thought.

I either get a list of stretched images with CGSize(40, 24) or a list of UIBarButtonItem with CGSize(24, 24) lining up in the UINavigationBar one by one without spacing.

Are there anything other constraints I need to add to create the spacing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIButton*(^buttonWith)(NSString *) = ^(NSString *imageName) {
    CGFloat size = 40.0;
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size, size)];
    [button setImage: [[UIImage imageNamed: imageName] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: button attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier: 1.0 constant: size]];
    [button addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: button attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier: 1.0 constant: size]];
    return button;
};
```

Usage:

```
UIButton *resetButton = buttonWith(@"reset");
self.resetBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: resetButton];

UIButton *backButton = buttonWith(@"back");
self.backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: backButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[self.backBarButton, self.resetBarButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard you can place another UIBarButtonItem in between the buttons that need spacing. set the text to spaces only. see screen shots.

[image]

[image]

[image]